# Client - Server ObjectInputStream Error

Tags: java, client-server, objectinputstream

my code is this

```
try
    {
        //Connect to the login server
        socket = new Socket(hostName , 15000);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    .. //perform the login , if the login succeed make answ=1;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown host: " + hostName);
        StatusLabel.setText("Unknown host");
    }
    catch (ConnectException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection refused by host: " + hostName);
        StatusLabel.setText("Connection refused by host, server is down.");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try 
        {
            //Finaly closing the connection
            socket.close();
            System.out.flush();
            System.out.println("Socket Closed");
                            //closing the output and input stream
            out.close();
            input.close();
            setVisible(false); //closing the window
        }
        catch (IOException e ) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't close socket");
        }
    }
    if(answ==1) //if the login suceed start the class for the game
    {
        Gumoku_Graphics g = new Gumoku_Graphics();
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.Play();
    }
```

inside Gumoku_Graphics() i call this class which performs the connection with the game server

```
Game n = new Game();
status=n.Connection();
```

which is

```
 public int Connection()  
{
    try {
        socket = new Socket(hostName, 15432);
        System.out.println("socket ok\n");

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("out ok\n");


        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("socket,out,input ok\n");
        return 1;
    }

    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown host: " + hostName);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (ConnectException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection refused by host: " + hostName);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and everytime it stops in "input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());" 
it can't do this and it stuck there.
It prints "socket ok", "out ok" and it stuck there.
Whats the problem? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ObjectInputStream documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.

As quoted the call will block until the header can be read.  You need to have some data to arrive from the socket before this call can continue.