# Client Handler Won't Start

Tags: java, windows, java-io

Im trying to make a basic email system in Java. I have a server that the clients connect to and a gui for the clients. When the server picks up a new connection from a client it starts a new thread running that handles all the different operations. The problem is that the server accepts the new client but doesnt start a new client handler thread running. Any help?

```
public class Server {
   public static Connection link;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
      final int PORT = 1234; // Define the sockets and ports and i/o
      Socket client;
      ClientHandler handler;

      try {
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         link = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:emails", "", "");
         System.out.println("Connected to Database . . . ");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
         System.out.println("* Unable to load driver! *");
         System.exit(1);
      } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
         System.out.println("* Cannot connect to database! *");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); // Set the server socket
      } catch (IOException ioEx) {
         System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!"); // If failed let the
                                                         // user know
         System.exit(1); // Exit the system with error code 1
      }

      System.out.println("\nServer running...\n"); // Tell the user the server
                                                   // is running

      do {
         client = serverSocket.accept();
         // Wait for client.
         System.out.println(client);
         handler = new ClientHandler(client);
         System.out.println(handler);
         System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n"); // Tell the user the
                                                         // server has accepted
                                                         // a client
         System.out.println("RUNNING");
         handler.start(); // Start the handler

      } while (true); // Continuous loop
   }

   static class ClientHandler extends Thread {
      /**
 * 
 */
      private Socket client;
      private ObjectInputStream input; // Define sockets, i/o and local array
                                       // list
      private ObjectOutputStream output;

      public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException // Client handler
                                                             // constructor
      {
         client = socket;
         input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());// Set client
                                                                // and i/o
                                                                // stream
         output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      }

      public void run() {
         String userCommand = null;
         System.out.println("RUNNING CLIENT HANDLER");
         boolean quit = false;

         do {

            try {
               userCommand = (String) input.readObject();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e2.printStackTrace();
            } // Receive user command

            if (userCommand.equals("SEND MESSAGE")) // If user command is to
                                                    // send a message
            {
               String username = null, recipient = null, message = null, insert, fileType = null;

               try {
                  username = (String) input.readObject();
                  recipient = (String) input.readObject(); // Receive username,
                                                           // recipient and
                                                           // message
                  message = (String) input.readObject();
                  fileType = (String) input.readObject();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               }

               insert = "INSERT INTO [emails] ([From], [To], [Message], [Attachment])"
                     + " VALUES('"
                     + username
                     + "','"
                     + recipient
                     + "','"
                     + message + "','" + fileType + "')";
               Statement statement = null;
               try {
                  statement = link.createStatement();
                  statement.executeUpdate(insert);
                  link.commit();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

               try {

                  getFile(input, fileType);
               } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                  ioEx.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
                  cnfEx.printStackTrace();
               }

               System.out.println(username // Tell the user a message has been
                                           // sent
                     + " sent message to " + recipient);
            }

            if (userCommand.equals("READ MESSAGE")) // If user command is to
                                                    // read a message
            {
               String username = null; // Define local variables

               try {
                  username = (String) input.readObject();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } // Receive the username of the current user
               Statement statement = null;
               String insert = "SELECT [Email No],[From],[Message],[Attachment] FROM [emails] WHERE To = '"
                     + username + "'";
               ResultSet rs = null;
               try {
                  statement = link.createStatement();
                  rs = statement.executeQuery(insert);
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

               try {
                  while (rs.next()) {
                     String from = rs.getString("From");
                     String message = rs.getString("Message");
                     String attachment = rs.getString("Attachment");
                     int emailNo = rs.getInt("Email no");
                     output.writeObject(from);
                     output.writeObject(message); // Send the username the
                                                  // message is from
                     output.writeObject(attachment);
                     output.writeObject(emailNo);
                     output.flush(); // and the message and flush the output
                                     // stream
                  }
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

               try {
                  output.writeObject("END");
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } // Send an end message
               try {
                  output.flush();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } // Flush the output stream

               System.out.println(username // Tell the user someone is reading
                                           // their messages
                     + " reading messages.");

            }

            if (userCommand.equals("QUIT")) // If the user command is quit
            {
               quit = true; // Set quit to true
            }

            if (userCommand.equals("DELETE MESSAGE")) // If the user command is
                                                      // delete a message
            {
               int valueToDelete = 0; // Define local variables

               try {
                  valueToDelete = Integer.parseInt((String) input.readObject());
               } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               } // Receive the value to delete
               Statement statement = null;
               String delete = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE [Email No] = "
                     + valueToDelete + "";
               try {
                  statement = link.createStatement();
                  statement.executeUpdate(delete);
                  link.commit();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
               System.out.println("Deleted message " + valueToDelete); // Tell
                                                                       // the
                                                                       // user a
                                                                       // message
                                                                       // has
                                                                       // been
                                                                       // deleted
            }
         } while (!quit); // Run while quit is false

         System.out.println("Client Closed"); // Tell the user the client has // closed
      }

      private static void getFile(ObjectInputStream inStream, String fileType)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

         byte[] byteArray = (byte[]) inStream.readObject();
         FileOutputStream mediaStream = null;

         if (fileType.equals("Text File"))
            mediaStream = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
         else if (fileType.equals("Image"))
            mediaStream = new FileOutputStream("file.gif");
         else if (fileType.equals("Movie"))
            mediaStream = new FileOutputStream("file.mpeg");

         mediaStream.write(byteArray);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that the program prints "New client accepted.\nRUNNING", but never says "RUNNING CLIENT HANDLER" -- is that the exact behavior?

Comment: The reason is the same as for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388253/client-server-objectinputstream-error/

Comment: It prints the client which tells me the local port and stuff but never gets past that.

Comment: Solved the problem by declaring the output stream before the input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are instantiating the ObjectInputStream it will block until the client sends a sufficient header, thus you never get to actually run the thread...  [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388253/client-server-objectinputstream-error/10388415#10388415)